# Numpy : efficient matrix indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays :

- `A` is of shape `(k, 4, 2)`
- `B` is of shape `(n, 12, 2)`

Where `k` and `n` are integers.

The coefficients of `B` are indexes of the matrix `A`. i.e, for instance, `B[0, 1, :]` is an array `[k, l]` and we are sure that `A[k , l]` exists.

What I would like to do is to build a Matrix `C` of the same size as `B`, such that, for all `i, j`,  `C[i, j] = A[B[i, j, 0], B[i, j, 1]]`

Is there an efficient way to do so ?

I have tried things like `A[:, B]`, `A[0, B]`, but it was unsuccesful. I could also do it with `for` loops but I think a implementation with numpy would be much faster.

For those who would like to try , I have prepared a little start-up code (with `k=n=2` to test the methods :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[
  [73,  -25],
  [97, -25],
  [73,  107],
  [97, 107]],

  [[81,  43],
  [86, 43],
  [81,  50],
  [86, 43]]
  ])

b = np.array(
  [[[0, 2],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 3],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0]],

   [[0, 3],
     [0, 2],
     [0, 1],
     [0, 0],
     [1, 0],
     [1, 2],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 3],
     [0, 0],
     [0, 0],
     [0, 0],
     [0, 0]]]
  )

#the answer should be :
c = np.array(
  [[[73,  107],
    [73,  -25],
    [97, 107],
    [97, -25],
    [81,  43],
    [81,  50],
    [86, 43],
    [86, 50],
    [73,  -25],
    [73,  -25],
    [73,  -25],
    [73,  -25]],

   [[97, 107],
     [73,  107],
     [97, -25],
     [73,  -25],
     [81,  43],
     [81,  50],
     [86, 43],
     [86, 50],
     [73,  -25],
     [73,  -25],
     [73,  -25],
     [73,  -25]],
     ]
     )
```

Hope this is clear for you,
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

`a[b[...,0],b[...,1]]`

should do the intended thing. You can do `b[:, :, 0]` instead of `b[..., 0]` but the latter one works for arrays with arbitrary dimensions, as long as you have your indexes at the last dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
C=A[B[:,:,0],B[:,:,1]]
```

But you confused me for a minute since your test `c` has few incorrect values:

```
>>> a,b,c = ...
>>> C = a[b[:,:,0],b[:,:,1]]
>>> np.all([C[i,j]==a[b[i,j,0],b[i,j,1]] for i in range(2) for j in range(12)])
True
>>> C==c
array([[[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I corrected the incorrect values